# Dropdown SQL List with PHP and update on click

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, sql

I have three dropdown lists. 
On the first one I choose something.
After that I have to choose something from the second dropdown.
But it has to be updated in the meanwhile. 
And from the second dropdown I have to choose something which changes the choosable items on the last dropdown.

I did already 3 lists but I am struggling with the POST function.
I guess that after choosing first item on dropdown it has to use the post function with autoreloading the page. The second droplist has to do something like list all where items = post from before. Right?

[image]

How can I handle that?

This is my code right now, but the part with POST is missing.

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX") or die("Connection Error: " . mysqli_error($conn));
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM XXX");
?>
<select name="dynamic_data">
<?php
$i=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
<option value="<?=$row["hersteller"];?>"><?=$row["hersteller"];?></option>
<?php
$i++;
}
?>
</select>
<?php
mysqli_close($conn);
?>

<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX") or die("Connection Error: " . mysqli_error($conn));
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM XXX");
?>
<select name="dynamic_data">
<?php
$i=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
<option value="<?=$row["model"];?>"><?=$row["model"];?></option>
<?php
$i++;
}
?>
</select>

<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "XX", "XXX", "XXX") or die("Connection Error: " . mysqli_error($conn));
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM XX");
?>
<select name="dynamic_data">
<?php
$i=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
<option value="<?=$row["motortyp"];?>"><?=$row["motortyp"];?></option>
<?php
$i++;
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Why are you opening so many connections? Also the or die part is very wrong, it will never do anything. Just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Use **.change** event on select(dropdown). In the event, call ajax method to populate data in 2nd drop down. Same goes for the 3rd drop down **like this**

```
$('#fristdropdownid').change(function(){
    var responseId = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       data:{responseId:responseId},
       url:'getdata.php',
       success:function(data){
         $('#seconddropdownid').html(data);
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your very fast answer. But i dont get it how i can implement your code. You write getdata.php Do i need another .php file? You also write .html?

Comment: In getdata.php file you will write query or whatever you want and return data to ajax call, **.html** set your output (from getdata.php) to dropdown